# cmake plugin syntax for LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES

Tags: android, cmake

I need to port `android.mk` into `cmake` script.

I can not find corresponding "`LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES`" in cmake script.

How to set "`LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES`" in cmake?

Comment: Did you figured it out? I'm having the same problem, I need to import all the symbols from a static library on Android's cmake. The only useful info that I found is on this link: https://www.twilio.com/blog/2016/03/building-native-android-libraries-with-the-latest-experimental-android-plugin.html

Answer (score 1):

this works for me

`target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} -Wl,--whole-archive libname -Wl,--no-whole-archive)`

Answer (score 0):

I think `-Wl` or `--whole-archive` should do this trick.